# chai-as-promised's eventually passes wrong rejection

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, testing, mocha.js, chai

suddenly I realized that in many of my tests it wrongly passes the fail test, I tried to understand the reason, here's is an example that passes the test which is wrong

```
describe('...', () => {
  it('...', () => {
    return chai.expect(Promise.reject('boom')).to.eventually.not.rejected;
  });
});
```

can anyone help me to figure out what am doing wrong? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`to.not.eventually` is not the same as `to.eventually.not`

**You’re using not, it should be before the eventually**
So change your test to below code to use `to.not.eventually` to see it won’t get passed and it’ll fail

```
const { describe, it } = require('mocha');
const chai = require('chai');
const chaiAsPromised = require('chai-as-promised');

chai.use(chaiAsPromised);
const { expect } = chai;

describe('...', () => {
  it('...', () => {
    return expect(Promise.reject(new Error('boom'))).to.not.eventually.rejected;
  });
});
```

Comment: THANKS! it should be in the documentation!